# What is the best solution to receive HTTP JSON Request in a PRISM WPF application context?

Tags: json, wcf, .net-core, prism

I´ve migrated a Prism WPF Application to .NET Core 3.1 but one project uses a WCF-Service which receives Http-Json-Post-Requests and I wasn´t able to find an alternative working in .NET Core 3 or .Netstandard...
In the previous .NET Framework version WCF calls published events by the IEventAggregator to execute EventHandlers in decoupled Prism modules...I tried to add a .NET Core Web Api project handling my HTTP requests but I could not host it in the Prism application or add my UnityContainer to the .NET Core Web Api project...does anyone have an idea how I can replace my WCF project with a .NET Core 3 project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by self hosting ASP.NET Core in a separate netstandard2.1 project, registering the class containing the WebHost to the UnityContainer of the PRISM application and injecting the UnityContainer to be used by the WebHost as IServiceCollection.